# 3.85 of LADR by Sheldon Axler

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

I'm a little confused on the proof of the implication of $(c)\to(a)$. In his proof, Axler says to take two elements $u_1, u_2$ of $U$ such that $v+u_1=w+u_2$. Whatever follows after that, I understand, but this beginning I don't. How can we just suppose this from $(c)$?
Here is the theorem:

Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $v,w\in V$. Then, the following are equivalent.

(a) $v-w\in U$

(b) $v+U=w+U$

(c) $(v+U)\cap(w+U)\neq \varnothing$

Comment: Hi Maries, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a useful guide to learn how to typeset equations in MathJax!

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to use this from now on :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Axler is assuming that $(v+U)\cap(w+U)\ne\emptyset$. So, take a vector $z\in(v+U)\cap(w+U)$. Then $z=v+u_1$ for some $u_1\in U$ (since $z\in v+U$) and $z=w+u_2$ for some $u_2\in U$ (since $z\in w+U$). But then $v+u_1=w+u_2$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

If you have that $(v+U)\cap (w+U)\neq \emptyset$, this means that exists an element $r\in (v+U)\cap (w+U)$ such that is in the intersection, and by the description of the set $v+U$, $r$ can be seen of the form $v+u_1$ for an $u_1\in U$. Analogously, since $r\in w+U$, it also can be seen as $w+u_2$ for an $u_2\in U$.

This imply that $v+u_1=r=w+u_2$, so $v-w=u_2-u_1$, and since $u_1,u_2\in U$, you have that $v-w=u_2-u_1\in U$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It's always a pleasure to be able to help :).